# use Outlook to send split zip files

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, attachments

I have trying to send a big file to someone whose email account cannot accept single email with large file and email is the only option for sending the file.

Currently I am using 7zip to split the files into 7 parts, and send it out one by one.

I am OK with this method, as this is the only method. But I wonder if Outlook can do the automation for me, usually I will send an introductory email out, indicating what I am going to send out later. Then I keep using the reply function to send create 7 new emails, added something like `zip part 01/07` on the title, and add a sentence like `zip part 01/07 attached` in the content, then attach the respective part of the split zip, and then click send.

Since I need to do the same operation for many times, and I think this is a bit dumb do to it manually. While this is not a very huge task for me to learn how to do it using VBA, is there any existing method available?

Answer (score 0):

A much easier solution would be to use one of the services that's designed to help with sending large files through email.  This will be much simpler and faster than the file splitting.

Here are some examples that have free accounts:

http://www.pando.com/

http://www.largefilesasap.com/

https://www.transferbigfiles.com/

The first one listed integrates with Outlook.